# Removed folder re-appears again

Tags: 11.10, command-line

please don't think I'm crazy, but a folder in ~/Downloads which I've deleted (via rmdir) appears again and again. Any idea what's wrong here?

The Ubuntu is Oneiric.

Comment: What's the folder called? Have you added any new scripts or applications lately? We need more information.

Comment: Have you solved your question?

Answer (score 2):

There are some "Special" directories in your home directory, Downloads are one of them.

=== Command line / manual method ===

edit `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` ,

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

it should look like this:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Delete or comment out ( add a `#` at the start) the `XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"` line

Then delete ~/Downloads

If that fails, install and run Ubuntu Tweak

http://ubuntu-tweak.com/

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Maybe this folder is set as the download folder in Firefox?

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers, but it's not that ~/Downloads reappears again and again after deleting, but a folder named "sammel3" *in* Downloads. As far as such an issue is concerned, I couldn't tell any modifications I've did to the pristine Oneiric. Any further ideas?